# Why my gradle task is not executing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to execute a gradle task in my android project. At the end of the module level build.gradle file I added the following

```
tasks.register("hello"){
doLast{
    println 'hellotask25'
}
}
```

When running **./gradlew hello** from the terminal the task runs as expected. Here is the output

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:hello
hellotask25

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 35s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

But when I do Build->Rebuild Project the task is not running. It is not showing in the Build console.

```
> Task :clean
> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 23s
30 actionable tasks: 30 executed
```

How do I solve this problem? I want to run this task when Anroid studio build my application

Comment: And why it should? rebuild calls `assembleDebug` task and it (and any other tasks) not depends on your task ... you need to set that `assembleDebug` depends on your task - how you can do this - well, it was already answered

Comment: so unless my task depends on any builtin tasks like `assembledebug` it won't run? Right?

Comment: no, the other way ... assembly have to depends on your task

Comment: So without adding a relation to those builtin tasks My tasks won't run

Comment: you are correct ... unless you call it manually

Comment: It is possible to run your task from Android Studio by double click on your task in tasks list - so the question is badly written - the real question is: how to run my task after build or something ... But then it's a duplicate ...

Comment: There is no gradle task list I can see. If it is duplicate provide the link to the duplicate question